# Count the number of ways to combine LEGO bricks

Tags: algorithm, combinations, combinatorics, lego-mindstorms

I have an arbitrary array of lego bricks. I also have some figures made of 3 lego bricks. I want to find out how many combinations of figures I can create of the current array of lego bricks.

Anybody have some references for me, so I can solve this problem?

Which algorithms can I use? Any theory I can use?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

/Hans

---

Edit: This question was [re-asked on the math stack exchange.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130166/combinations-of-lego-bricks-figures-in-an-array-of-random-bricks)

Comment: Are all Lego bricks identical? If not, how many distinct types of bricks are there? Does "figures" made up of unique set of bricks? You should put more thought and effort into your question.

Comment: I have six brick colors, so the array of bricks could be:
blue, red, red, yellow, green, yellow, orange, blue, yellow, white. The figures is made of 3 bricks. The different figures are: 1: yellow, white, blue; 2: blue, yellow, green; 3: yellow, orange, blue; 4: yellow, red, yellow; 5: yellow, blue;

Comment: Now, any combination of three is a valid combination?

Comment: No, I only have these combinations: 1 (yellow, white, blue), 2 (blue, yellow, green), 3 (yellow, orange, blue), 4 (yellow, red, yellow), 5 (yellow, blue)

Comment: Let us take only figure 1. Assume we have 2 yellow, 3 white and 4 blue blocks. What is the number of combinations just for figure 1 (yellow, white, blue)?

Comment: Two of figure 1. Leftover: 1 x white, 2 x blue.

Comment: Do bricks have to be adjacent in array to be able to form a figure? If not then why are we talking about arrays and not about [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)?

Comment: No, the bricks do not need to be adjacent. I have no knowledge of multisets, but I will definitely look more closely into that subject.

Comment: I have asked the same question in the Mathematics forum. It is explained a bit differently, so maybe it can clear up some of the confusion. [Combinations of lego bricks figures in an array of random bricks](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130166/combinations-of-lego-bricks-figures-in-an-array-of-random-bricks)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it belongs exclusively on _Mathematics_, unless you intend to use a programming language to determine the answer. Please declare the cross-posting on the other question as well, so people do not duplicate effort. Edit: I've flagged this question as off-topic, so please add a comment if this is definitely a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you believe that problems like this, or at least their general cases, are actually still *open research questions*? You're doing real mathematical research here. ;)

Søren Eilers, Mikkel Abrahamsen, and Bergfinnur Durhuus did some work on a LEGO-combination counting problem, namely counting the [number of unique ways you can arrange six identical 4x2 lego bricks.](http://www.math.ku.dk/~eilers/lego.html) You may be able to look at their work (includes Java code) for inspiration.

From a skim over the text, it appears they solved the problem two separate ways:

1. Using a recursive block-positioning and counting algorithm.
2. Using brute force - trying every possible positioning of the six bricks in space (even those for which the bricks don't touch.)

Hint: The number of possible combinations, even for small numbers of bricks, is **large**. This is what makes LEGO so fun.

Comment: Incidentally, it may be worth asking this question on math.stackexchange.com. This is really a mathematics question, and mathematicians will be able to give better answers on it.

Comment: Thank you very much Li-aung Yip! I'll ask the question in the other forum.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the computational complexity you are expecting you can use dynamic programming.

Let x1,x2,...xk be a solution such that x1 copies of combination 1, x2 copies of combination 2 ....

F([]) = F([x1=0]+F([x1=1]...

F([x1]) = F( [x1,x2=0]) + F( [x1,x2=1])....

The complexity of this solution is O(n^k) where n is the number of bricks and k is the number of figures.

Comment: That's an awfully generic answer - how is dynamic programming relevant to the task at hand?

Comment: @Li-aungYip Why? This is a very accurate answer. What part do you not understand? Basically pick how many replicas of shape 1 you want to build and use the rest of the bricks to build other shapes.